# SVN Merge don't work

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have a trunk and a branch. I have made some changes to branch an commit the change.

Lets say revision no is 5525.

Now I want my branch change for only this commit to be merged back to trunk.

I ran the command on trunk

```
svn merge --dry-run -c 5525 <url>/branch/
```

Nothing seems to be updated/merged. It showed me blank.
Then I go on and try seeing the eligible revisions to be merged.

```
svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible  <url>/branch/
```

5525 is in there in the list, that means its eligible for merging.
Whats wrong?

Please help.
thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example starting from an empty repository and creating the trunk/branch of what you're doing that shows this behavior.  Also please specify which version of Subversion you're using.  It's very hard to diagnose merge issues in the abstract, the history is very important to merge decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Run it without the `--dry-run` argument. This argument is only to test the merge, but doesn't do any real merging into your working copy.

Comment: yeah, thats known I was testing if the corresponding file been changing on trunk before running the actual merge. Its NOT :(